# Any spec detailing physical properties (length, area, shape) and sillicon dopping concentration of standard NPN transistors such as BC 107?

Tags: transistors, physical-design, silicon

I'm trying to find the physical constructive parameters (especially doping levels) of the common NPN transistor BC 107/108/109 but I can't find any resource detailing this things, only the standard sheets with the traditional electrical specs.

Reverse engineer isn't giving me all the  details, leaving me with undefined use cases...

Comment: Micrographs are available, but good luck with doping. What for? They're basically stock items from any bipolar process of comparable voltage rating.

Comment: A BC107, BC108 and BC109 are VERY old. I used them 56 years ago in their metal package. I think newer BC547, BC548 and BC549 have the same old chip in a new epoxy or plastic package.

Comment: There are companies that can reverse-engineer this sort of thing for you, down to using mass spectrometry to measure doping levels. But such a process is extremely expensive--what's your budget for this project?